# how to keep proportions in jpeg image when importing it to rstudio

Tags: jpeg, rstudio

Is there any way to import a jpeg image in Rstudio or R and keep its original proportions? The following way used to work for me, but not anymore.

```
require(jpeg)
image=readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))
plot(1, type="n", xlim=c(1, ncol(image)), ylim=c(1, nrow(image)))
rasterImage(image,xleft=1, xright=ncol(image), ybottom=1,  ytop=nrow(image))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your underlying plot has a fixed aspect ratio of one.

```
plot(1, type="n", xlim=c(1, ncol(image)), ylim=c(1, nrow(image)), asp=1)
```

Otherwise the plot will just stretch to whatever aspect ratio the graphics window is, and the raster is "glued" to the plot such that it stretches too.